# How do I simulate Int32 overflow?

Tags: java, vba, excel

A co-worker of mines developed something in Java that does some simple calculations in Java. I am converting the code to VBA but I realized that once the calculations result in 11 digits or more, the calculations are out of sync.

Java code

```
int prime = 31;
int result = 1;
String test = "Periwinkle"

for (char c : test.toCharArray()) {
 result = prime * result + Character.getNumericValue(c);
 System.out.println("letter " + c + " number " + Character.getNumericValue(c));
 System.out.println(result + " from " + c);
}
 System.out.println(Math.abs(result));
```

VBA Code

```
Dim arr As Variant
Dim letr As String
Dim num As Integer
Dim result, prime As Integer

For Each cell In Range("A1") 'A1 = Periwinkle
    result = 1
    prime = 31
    arr = CharacterArray(cell.value)
 For Each element In arr
    letr = element
    'Debug.Print "Letter: " & letr
    num = getNumber(letr)
    'Debug.Print "Number: " & num
    result = prime * result + num
    'Debug.Print "Result: " & result
    Cells(cell.Row, 3).value = Math.Abs(result)
 Next
Next
```

All the calculations are in sync until the letter "n" in which the calculation in Java results in "-1413090664" while in VBA results in "50126516888". The problem is that in Java since `result` is defined as an `int`, it cannot hold up to 11 digits thus resulting in the negative number.

Note: I'm aware that I can change the Java code to use a double instead however I cannot make this change. I'm looking for a workaround in VB.

**I need to mimic the Java code as much as possible, so I need the VBA code to simulate an unchecked Int32 overflow. How can this be done?**

Comment: Use a double? I don't understand your problem

Comment: Is the integer overflow on the java side really intended behaviour? It seems the java side should be changed, is that correct?

Comment: @redFIVE, I would love to use the double, but essentially the java code is set in stone. I cannot make changes to it. These codes essentially generate sku numbers which we cannot change.

Comment: @JornVernee yes, the java side should be changed due to the overflow but I can't :/

Comment: @redFIVE I hear you but... I guess sometimes it is what it is..

Comment: Tbh I don't know much about VBA, but [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/06bkb8w2.aspx) says an ```Integer``` is signed 32 bits, (just like it is in java). A value of ```50,126,516,888``` should not even be possible (according to the doc).

Comment: @JornVernee I'm aware of that, but I've converted the number to a string which makes it displayable on the spreadsheet.

Comment: Your `result` is a `Variant`, which will take whichever type is applicable (and change when it needs to). `Dim result, prime As Integer` only gives `prime` a type. Try `Dim result As Long, prime As Long` if you intend both to be Int32's. Note that VBA will blow up when the value overflows, so good luck reproducing that without jumping through hoops.

Comment: @JornVernee that doc is for VB.NET - an `Integer` is 16-bit in VBA, so the correct VBA type for an `Int32` would be a `Long`. VBA docs are becoming quite hard to search, everything points to VB.NET these days.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thanks for the suggestion. I've already tried changing it to a long type instead but it does the same thing. VBA did not blow up as intended to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to disable the overflow check, but you can avoid it by working with two int32.
This VBA function will get you the exact same result:

```
Sub Usage()
  Debug.Print Hash("Periwinkle")
End Sub

Public Function Hash(text As String) As Long
  Dim lo&, hi&, i%
  lo = 1
  For i = 1 To Len(text)
    lo = 31& * (lo And 65535) + GetNumericValue(AscW(Mid$(text, i, 1)))
    hi = 31& * (hi And 65535) + (lo \ 65536)
  Next
  Hash = Abs((lo And 65535) + (hi And 32767) * 65536 + (&H80000000 And -(hi And 32768)))
End Function

Private Function GetNumericValue(ByVal c As Integer) As Integer
  Select Case c
    Case 48 To 57:   GetNumericValue = c - 48  '[0-9]'
    Case 65 To 90:   GetNumericValue = c - 55  '[A-Z]'
    Case 97 To 122:  GetNumericValue = c - 87  '[a-z]'
    Case 188 To 190: GetNumericValue = -2
    Case 178:        GetNumericValue = 2
    Case 179:        GetNumericValue = 3
    Case 185:        GetNumericValue = 1
    Case Else:       GetNumericValue = -1
  End Select
End Function
```

Note that the Java code is computing a hash derived from the FNV algorithm.

Comment: Sir you are a genius. If I could triple upvote this I would.